# Fastify cookie setup not working from subdomain

Tags: javascript, cors, fastify, fastify-cookie

I've scoured the internet for a while, but haven't been able to find out what I might be doing wrong.
I've a fastify server which is hosted on a subdomain: `https://api.example.com`

The UI is served via [CloudFlare pages](https://pages.cloudflare.com/) on the domain `https://example.com` and it's a react-app.

Now I am calling the `/authenticate` endpoint in my backend via the `fetch` in the UI as:

```
 const requestOptions: RequestInit = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      redirect: "follow",
      referrerPolicy: "no-referrer",
      body: JSON.stringify({ message })
    };

return fetch(`${SERVER_URI}/authenticate`, requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => console.log({ result }));
```

On the backend I am using the following setup:

```
 // Setup the CORS package
 await fastify.register(require('@fastify/cors'), {
    origin: /example\.com$/,
    methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE']
  });


// Cookies Manager
fastify.register(require('@fastify/cookie'), {
    secret: 'someSecret'
});
```

When the `/authenticate` endpoint is called, it goes to a method which should set the cookie in the browser by running the following code:

```
AuthController.js:
...

res
  .setCookie('__auth', token, {
    domain: '.example.com',
    path: '/',
    signed: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: 'Lax'
  })
  .send({ authenticated: true, meta: {} });
```

- I tried to add `credentials: 'include'` in the fetch call from the UI, that didn't help.
- I read about the different properties and headers that are available, but I am definitely missing something which has lead me to stackoverflow.

Expectation:

- Cookie to be set in the browser.

Comment: `/example\.com$/` is insecure, since it also matches Web origins like `https://notexample.com`.

Comment: You write: _I tried to add `credentials: 'include'` in the fetch call from the UI, that didn't help._ That is a necessary condition for the cookie to get set, though. You will also need to allow credentials in your CORS configuration.